# How to change a single setting across multiple images in Canon DPP?

Tags: canon, raw, photo-editing

I am using Canon Digital Photo Professional to process a large quantity of images I took in an event. After some work on individual pictures, I realized that merely all of them will benefit from lifting the sharpness a little bit.

DPP allows you to define recipes, but AFAIK a recipe will adjust all of the RAW settings. Is there a way of selecting all images and adjusting just the sharpness (or any other single setting, for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to select all the required images from the regular folder window (using Ctrl/Shift for multiple selections). Then, click the **Tool** button at the top left toolbar to open the **Tool palette** and adjust the global settings.